# How to apply deep learning for classifying each line in resume?

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science, analysis

I have a question about analyzing resumes, can I perform that using deep learning?
By passing each line in resume into deep learning model, then it will predict if this line is {Education, Work Experience and Others}!
Any advice please.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for what i gather from your question you do not know much about deep learning. but what you are saying is possible by doing the following steps: 1. text reading 2. text preprocessing 3. text classification via some good classification algorithm. if you want deep learning then Neural network or big gun like RNN. i suggest to take some course on Machine Learning

Comment: I know deep learning, and had taken some of maching learning courses, and deep learning courses, and I know RNN.
But the idea is: if I can use RNN for performing like this projects?

Comment: Thank you so much bro, then I just need a dataset that have lines and labels for each line, then train the model with this dataset!